# Is the angel in Revelation 10:3 Jesus?

Tags: word-study, revelation

Revelation 10:3 says:

> And cried with a loud voice, as when a lion roareth: and when he had cried, seven thunders uttered their voices.

The fact that this angel is referred to as roaring like a lion I find interesting. Could it have any reference to Jesus as the Lion of the tribe of Judah?

Comment: Perhaps, although the verse doesn't say, "when *the* lion roareth", but "*as* when *a* lion roareth". Also, Jesus is never depicted as a roaring lion, but simply as **the** lion of Judah. Although, maybe I'm missing something. Either way, welcome to Biblical Hermeneutics Stack Exchange! Hope you find it welcoming here. +1 :)

Comment: Thanks @Rajesh!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Jamieson-Fausset-Brown Bible Commentary offers this comment:

> And I saw another mighty angel; the most and best interpreters
> understand by this angel, Christ, formerly represented to us as a
> Lamb, here as an Angel; none but he could call the two witnesses,
> Revelation 11:3, his witnesses; besides, the glorious appearance of
> this angel speaketh him no ordinary angel.

While not all agree, the identification of the angel of Rev 10 with Christ is on the following basis of the description which is so similar to other descriptions of Jesus:

- "wrapped in a cloud" similar to the description of Jesus in Rev 14:14
- "rainbow above his head" similar to Rev 4:3 and Eze 1:28
- "face shining like the sun" as in Matt 17:2, Rev 1:16
- "legs like pillars of fire" as in Rev 1:15
- "raised right hand" like that in Dan 12:7

**APPENDIX - Angel of the LORD**

The following passages make it clear that the “Angel of the LORD” is almost always, the LORD (Jehovah) Himself, probably Jesus in particular.  Gen 16:7-13, 22:11-17, 32:24-30, 48:16, Ex 3:2-6, 32:34, Num 22:22-35, Josh 5:13-15, Judg 2:1-4, 6:11-23, 13:3-23, Isa 63:9, Dan 3:25, 28, Hos 12:4, 5, Zech 3:1-7, Mal 3:1.

A closely related phrase, “Angel of God” who is clearly God as in Gen 6:13, 8:15, 9:8, 17, 15:13, 17:3, 4, 21:12, 16-21, 35:1, 10, Ex 4:3-8, 6:2, 23:20, 21, Deut 1:6, 1 Kings 12:22, etc.  See also Acts 10:3, 4, Gal 4:14.

In Isa 63:9, “the Angel of His [LORD’s] presence saved them”, and is almost certainly a reference to the same being.  The same is true of Ex 23:20, 21, Josh 5:13-15.

In view of the clear statements in John 1:18, 5:37, 6:46, 1 John 4:12 that no one has seen God the Father, and the numerous cases listed above of people seeing the LORD and the Angel of the LORD, etc, it appears that these epiphanies were of the pre-incarnate Jesus.

In other places we see that the LORD sends the LORD:

- Zech 2:6-12 – the LORD (= YHWH) claims three times that He has been sent by the LORD.
- Isa 48:11-16 – again, the LORD has been sent by the LORD.

Thus, unsurprisingly, Jesus is the messenger to the human race and underlines the importance that the Godhead places upon such messages.

This is not to suggest that Jesus is an angel in the sense that He is less that God; far from it!  However, the Greek and Hebrew word for “angel” simply means messenger and it is in this sense that Jesus is the messenger in the above passages.

Answer (score 1):

In a word, "no." The first verse of Revelation 10 reads, "And I saw ANOTHER strong angel coming down out of heaven, etc. It's impossible for this angel to be the Lord Jesus Christ because Jesus is "NOT" an actual angel as some religions teach.

The word "ANOTHER" comes from Revelation 8:2-3. In other words, John states, "And I saw the seven angels who stand before God; and seven trumpets were given to them. Vs3, "And another angel came and stood at the altar, holden a golden censer etc.

There is also more evidence that Jesus is not this angel in Revelation 10:3. God the Father says of His Son at Hebrews 1:6, "And again when He brings the first-born into the world, He says, "And let all the angels of God worship Him." The Greek word used for worship is "proskuneo."

This same Greek word is used at Luke 4:8 where Jesus says, "It is written, You shall worship (proskuneo) the Lord your God and serve Him only." This is actual "worship" and not simply paying "obeisance."

Now, as Dottard explained Jesus Christ appeared as "THE" angel/messenger of the Lord in the Old Testament before His incarnation as a permanent man which is explained at Hebrews 1:1-3.There is plenty of Biblical evidence to support what I just stated if your interested. For now I'm only dealing with your immediate question regarding Revelation 10:3.

Answer (score 0):

Simply, no. Jesus is not an angel or the Angel OF God except by extrapolation and unbiblical reasoning.

> I saw another strong angel coming down from heaven v1

There is no relevance to 'another' angel being *somehow* Jesus or anything other than - 'another angel'. The many references claimed by another answer are fine examples of treating scripture with recklessness, imagination and ignoring plain scripture that expresses truth, like -

> But now you seek to kill me, a man who has spoken to you the truth that I heard from God. Abraham did not do this. John 8:40

Jesus claims here to be a man - to make him any more than this is to make him a liar. The only way to make him an angel or an angel of the Lord is to draw personal conclusions that scripture does not support. The Apostles and God tells us that Jesus is a man.

> Rom 5:15 …the gift that came by the grace of the one man, Jesus Christ. Gal 4:4 God sent His son, born of a woman. 1 Cor 15:21 ’for by a man came death, by a man also came resurrection of the dead’. He (God) will judge the world with justice by the man He has appointed. He has given proof of this to everyone by raising him from the dead." Acts 17:31 1 Tim 2:5 For there is one God and one mediator between God and mankind, the man Christ Jesus.
> Acts 2:22 ‘a man approved of God’.

Based on the Rev. text referenced, sound reasoning and other scripture, no, Jesus is *not* the angel in Revelation 10:3. Furthermore, *scripture* explicitly titles Jesus as the Son of God and the Son of Man - never an angel of any description.